# How to combine each line of two files together using sed or awk?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have two files. File `A` has a list of words, one on each line. File `B` contains another huge list of words, but some are quite long. How would I use sed or awk to take each line from file `A` and combine it with each line in file `B` that isn't longer that 6 characters? It would ideally spit out all the results in a new file.

For example:

File A:

```
cool
beans
sad
```

File B:

```
armadillo
snake
bread
```

New File:

```
coolsnake
coolbread
beanssnake
beanbread
sadsnake
sadbread
```

Comment: @lesmana, nope. I'm trying desperately to create a cool word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not same order that your output, but could be useful:

```
awk '
  FNR == NR { 
    words[ $1 ] = 1; 
      next 
  } 
  FNR < NR { 
    if ( length( $1 ) <= 6 ) 
      for ( word in words ) { 
        print word $0 
       } 
  }
' fileA fileB
```

Output:

```
coolsnake
sadsnake
beanssnake
coolbread
sadbread
beansbread
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's|.*|sed "/......./d;s/.*/&\&/" fileB|' fileA | sh
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's|.*|sed "/......./d;s/.*/&\&/" fileB|e' fileA
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line1; do
 while read line2;do
   [[ $(echo $line2 | wc -c) -lt 7 ]] && \
   echo $line1$line2
 done < './B.txt'
done < './A.txt'
```

something like that, just fit it for yourself
it gives me:

```
coolsnake
coolbread
beanssnake
beansbread
sadsnake
sadbread
```

Comment: +1 but prefer `[[ ${#line2} -lt 7 ]] && echo $line1$line2` for string length comparison.

Comment: yeah, it's better, and probably faster.

Comment: @anubhava: In Bash, it's preferred to use this form for integer comparisons: `(( ${#line2} < 7 ))`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Agreed, that form of numeric expression/comparison is even better.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

die qq[Usage: perl $0 <fileA> <fileB>\n] unless @ARGV == 2;

open my $fh, q[<], pop or die $!;

my @words = map { chomp; $_ } grep { length( $_ ) <= 6 } <$fh>;

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    for my $word ( @words ) {
        printf qq[%s\n], $_ . $word;
    }
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl fileA fileB
```

With following output:

```
coolsnake
coolbread
beanssnake
beansbread
sadsnake
sadbread
```

Answer (score 1):

with bash:

```
mapfile -t shortwords < <(sed -r 's/.{7,}/d' B.txt)
while read word; do
  for suffix in "${shortwords[@]}"; do
    echo "$word$suffix"
  done
done < A.txt
```